# How to get value from dynamic EditText and store the values in a integer array?

Tags: android, arraylist, dynamic, android-edittext

I am testing a new app on which I implemented dynamic EditText, but got stuck with a problem. I added Editexts to a List array, and I am trying to get the value from EditText and save it to an integer array, but when I click on a button I am getting empty value.

My code:

```java
List<EditText> all_value1 = new ArrayList<EditText>();
TextView textView = new TextView(this);
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    editText1 = new EditText(this);
    editText1.setInputType(TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
        all_value1.add(editText1);  
    linearlayout.addView(editText1);
}

int a[] = new int[all_value1.size()]

for(int i = 0; i < all_value.size(); i++) {
    a[i] = Integer.parseInt(all_value1.get(i).getText().toString());
}

Button b = new Button(this);
b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnCLickListener() {
    @override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        textView.setText(String.valueOf(a[0])); //I dont want to use all_value1.get(0).getText().toString()
    }
})
```

My expectation is to store all the edittexts values to an integer array, and on button click I should get a specific value from that array.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have written the above code in onCreate() method, initially all your edit texts would be empty so your `Integer.parseInt(all_value1.get(i).getText().toString())` will throw a *NumberFormatException*.
A try catch solution such as :

```
for (int i = 0; i < all_value1.size(); i++) {
            try {
                c[i] = Integer.parseInt(all_value1.get(i).getText().toString());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                c[i] = 0;
            }
 }
```

is of no use as this will initialize the complete array a[] with 0s and you'll have to assign a *TextChangedListener* to all your edit texts if you want something to happen ( i.e. changing the value of corresponding a[i] ) when you type something in your EditText.

A simple solution would be to make the array not of integer type but of EditText type itself (if you really do not want to use the get() function every time button is clicked).

Try the following code :

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    List<EditText> all_value1 = new ArrayList<>();
    final TextView textView = new TextView(this);
    EditText editText1;
    LinearLayout linearLayout = findViewById(R.id.ll);
    linearLayout.addView(textView);
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        editText1 = new EditText(this);
        editText1.setInputType(TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
        all_value1.add(editText1);
        linearLayout.addView(editText1);
    }

    final EditText a[] = new EditText[all_value1.size()];

    for (int i = 0; i < all_value1.size(); i++) {
        a[i] = all_value1.get(i);
    }

    Button b = new Button(this);
    linearLayout.addView(b);
    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            textView.setText(a[0].getText().toString());
        }
    });
}
```

If you want an int value you can use `Integer.parseInt(a[i].getText().toString())` after you have entered something in the EditText. 
This solution will make the button do its thing, if not satisfied you'll have do assign listeners to EditText(s).

Comment: I want to store those text view values to another array called int edittextvalues[] = new int[5]; this is what I was asking if I do this I am getting numberformatexcsption

Comment: That's because all the work ( initialization of arrays and assigning values ) is being done when onCreate() is called. Initially there is nothing in EditText so it is obvious that you'll get an exception as the string in EditText is "" which is not an integer. Whatever you want to do with the integer values just pass the EditText array to a function where you can use Integer.parseInt(a[i].getText().toString()). Study about android activity lifecycles if you are not sure what's being computed when.